# How to lengthen lifeline of sequence diagram in Dia?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, dia

I want to make sequence diagram by using UML diagram set in Dia. Can I modify or lengthen the rectangle of the lifeline? When I extend it, only the dashed line that extends.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The dashed line is the lifeline (see [here](http://uml-diagrams.org) for an explanation). What you want to do is extend the execution occurrence (the wide rectangle). To do this, right click on the occurrence and select "Add connection points".

Comment: Thanks, I've just known how to add connection points. Previously, I added unnamed "dummy" method to do this.